# How to stop Kazam recording after X minutes

Tags: ubuntu

I enrolled a course, and I was absent the previous session. So I can play the recorded course online.

I installed Kazam to record this course (because it will be deleted after two weeks), and I want to automatically stop recording after X minutes (each session is around 6 hours). I saw `man kazam` but did not see any commands to stop.

I use Ubuntu 20.04. Is that possible? I did not find anything in `man kazam`.

Comment: You used Kazam to record a course, and now you're viewing it again and using Kazam to try to record locally only a portion of it? Or are you viewing the original course again and recording it again? I'm not familiar with Kazam, but assuming it's a CLI utility, can you use the built in task scheduler (it's name escapes me at the moment) to send the relevant commands at the appropriate time to end the recording.

Comment: @music2myear I did edit the question to make it more readable.